# exclude all rows for an ID if 1 row meets condition in Power BI (DAX)

Tags: dax

Similar to this [exclude all rows for an ID if 1 row meets condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41451891/exclude-all-rows-for-an-id-if-1-row-meets-condition) but in DAX

Comment: Can you add some example data, and what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have data like this one in table 'Contacts':

```
ClientId | ContactId | Guardian
123      | 1         | Y
123      | 2         | N
123      | 3         | N
456      | 4         | N
456      | 5         | N
456      | 6         | N
```

[image]

And our goal is to exclude ClientId = 123 (because Guardian =y)

```
NewTable =
var __ToExclude = 
    summarizecolumns(
    'Contacts'ClientId
    ,FILTER(VALUES('Contacts'[Guardian]), 'Contacts'[Guardian] = "Y")
    )

return

summarizecolumns(
'Contacts'ClientId
,FILTER(VALUES('Contacts'ClientId),  not ('Contacts'ClientId in __ToExclude ))
)
```

[image]

Comment: and how would you create the new relationship? It is not working for me right now.

Comment: This is still only eliminating Client ID 123 for the one row that has Y, not the others.

Comment: How did you test this solution? I added screenshots with powerbi showing that everything is ok and working as expected. The solution shows only rows for clients that do not have a value of Y in the Guardian column